Couldn't see the approved & published public app on Apple Store
My app is approved 5 days back under TestFlight

I published the approved app right away, I can see the Ready for Distribution and green tick too in a few hours 5 days back

Or is there still something that needs to be catered???

But still, I couldn't see the app on the Apple Store, when I click to view. It always go to a dead end screen showing Connecting...

Why??? Is the Apple store working fine or is some downtime going on, I guess it shouldn't be so long.
NOTE: I'm publishing this app on the Apple store for the first time and I have few apps already published on this account


Here it will not give the correct link until all countries (or at least the US) are not selected to publish your app
